# Select all not working after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using an ajax to load form fields. When the you select the school, the grade fields load. When you select the grade, the show name check box appears. When the select all box appears, I have to click the select all box twice for it to work. It like the checkboxes are not apart of the DOM until the second click.  I am not really sure what the issue is.
Here is all of my code.

[Main Page](http://pastebin.com/N1muHmVm)

[ShowGrade.html](http://pastebin.com/MyQMzRQJ)

showname.html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="coursereportcheckall" onChange="ThirdCheck();" id="checkall" name="coursereportcheckall">Select All<br>
<input type="checkbox" onChange="FourthCheck(this.selectedIndex);" value="10" class="tid" id="tid" name="tid"> George Washington<br>
<input type="checkbox" onChange="FourthCheck(this.selectedIndex);" value="11" class="tid" id="tid" name="tid"> John Adams<br>
```

showcourse.html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkallcourse">Select All<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cid" id="cid" class="cid" value="12"/> Twelve<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cid" id="cid" class="cid" value="13"/> Thirteen<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cid" id="cid" class="cid" value="14"/> Fourteen<br />
```

Comment: You need to look into delegation. Start with jQuery's on() handler - https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

You will want to move your jQuery "on" outside of the ThirdCheck function. This should be set on jquery loaded, not when clicking on the checkbox.

```
$(document).on('click', '.#checkall', function(event) ...
```

Your problem is the click handler is being set the first time you click and then is being executed the second time you click.

Also, you don't need to include the "." in front of '.#checkall'.